# Including valgrind in makefile

Tags: c++, linux

Is it possible to include valgrind option in makefile for an interactive application?
If yes,then how?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, it is, since any command can be run in your `Makefile`. What did you try?

Comment: Forget makefiles, what *is* a valgrind option for an interactive application?

Answer (score 2):

You actually do something like the following for a `mycode.c`:

#### Makefile

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

all: mycode

valgrind:
        valgrind ./mycode

clean:
        rm -f mycode
```

You can run:

```
 make clean all valgrind
```

to clean up, build and trigger valgrind completely.

Answer (score -3):

I am not a valgrind´s expert, and I don´t know if is possible include inside of the makefile, but what is the reason to include valgrind? To use valgrind, you only need execute your program calling previously to valgrind, like this:

yourprompt$valgrind ./YourProgram

anyway, if anyone knows valgrind in detail, I am also interested in knowing the answer

regards